# Error when trying to view the Application Properties page in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7.2

When trying to open the Properties of a WPF application, on the Application page, it gives the following error:

> An error occurred trying to load the page. The method or operation is not implemented.

[image: screenshot]

In the Windows Event Viewer I  can find this:

```
Error Information 
AppInsightsEvent Name = vs/ml/proppages/appdesigner/prop-page-designer-view-fault
Description           = ActivatePage
TelemetrySession      = '4a288b83-00d2-4f45-84cf-513352811580' Started = True OptIn=True IsInitialized = True Cloned = False
WatsonEventType       = VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2
UTC time              = 2019-03-07T10:27:40

Exception:  System.NotImplementedException  
The method or operation is not implemented. 

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.WPF.ApplicationPropPageVBWPF.StartupObjectOrUri.GetHashCode()
System.Collections.Hashtable.GetHash(Object key) 
System.Collections.Hashtable.InitHash(Object key, Int32 hashsize, UInt32& seed, UInt32& incr) 
System.Collections.Hashtable.ContainsKey(Object key) 
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ComboBoxItemAccessibleObjectCollection.get_Item(Object key) 
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ComboBoxUiaProvider.SetComboBoxItemSelection()
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) 
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value) 
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedItem(Object value) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.WPF.ApplicationPropPageVBWPF.SetSelectedStartupObjectOrUriIntoCombobox(ComboBox combobox, StartupObjectOrUri startupObjectOrUri) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.WPF.ApplicationPropPageVBWPF.SetStartupObjectOrUriIntoUI(Control control, PropertyDescriptor prop, Object value) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.PropertyControlData.InitPropertyUI()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.PropPageUserControlBase.InitPage()
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.PropPageUserControlBase.SetObjects(Object[] objects) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.PropPageUserControlBase.IPropertyPageInternal_SetObjects(Object[] objects) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.PropPageBase.Create(IntPtr hWndParent) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropertyPages.PropPageBase.IPropertyPage2_Activate(IntPtr hWndParent, RECT[] pRect, Int32 bModal) 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.PropPageDesigner.PropPageDesignerView.ActivatePage(IPropertyPage PropPage)
```

### What I've Tried

- I previously installed the Visual Studio 2019 RC, but have now uninstalled it. That version also gave the same error.
- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2017 didn't help.
- This happens in old and freshly created projects.
- My coworker doesn't have this on his computer with the same projects.
- I did not have any problems last week. I haven't installed/uninstalled anything special.

Comment: It sounds like VS 2019 has replaced a file that VS 2017 was using and now you're stuck with it. All I can suggest is trying to find out what file that is and replacing it with a good one, maybe copied from your coworkers PC. You may be able to compare files on your machine and theirs to determine what differences there are. It would be a pain but it may be necessary, if even reinstalling CS 2017 doesn't help.

Comment: I was able to access the page before, when both versions were installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Fix*: Update to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 - 15.9.19+

[image]

It appears this was only a problem for `.vbproj` project types.

This was also reported in:

- the [dotnet/project-system github repo issues](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/4751)
- this Developer Community issue on the [Project Properties Build Page Blank](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/460020/project-properties-build-page-blank.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:
Please do the following to fix your issue:

- Quit VS 2017
- Launch VS 2017 Installer.
- Click Modify.
- Check the ".NET desktop development" workload. If checked, uncheck and then check in second run (uninstall - install)
- Click Modify.
- Reload your project

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Visual Studio 2017 15.9. I've installed an older version of Visual Studio (15.6) and the problem went away.

Installing an Earlier Release of Visual Studio 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017

Comment: Good News! Seems like there's a fix to roll the version forward to `15.9.19` instead of back to `15.6`

Answer (score 1):

I just open *.csproj file and change **TargetFrameworkVersion** to v4.7.5 and it partially fixed the problem. My project was originally developed under .NET 3.5. Now Application Tab opens, but doesn't compile. I can change desirable properties, and than change target version back to compile the project. Of course, it's not the solution.
PS. The solution is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/549137/known-issue-application-tab-of-vb-project-property.html